# How to use array filters of mongodb 3.6 in mgo framework?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Hi i have a situation where i have to update objects in nested array in mongodb collection using mgo framework of Go. As of now mongodb version 3.6 support this using ArrayFilters as a 3rd parameter in Collection.Update().The mgo Collection.Update() function only supports 2 parameters, one to find and another for update. How can i use arrayfilters in mgo's Collection.Update()

This is my object look like

```
{
  "TPID": "",
  "TPName":"",
  "TCID":"",
  "TCName":"",
  "BatchId":"",
  "BatchName":"",
  "QP":[{
    "qpCode":"",
       "jobRole":"",
       "Sector":"",
       "SectorID":"",

    "CompulsoryNos":[{
    "NosCode":"",
    "TotalMarks":"",
           "OutOf":"",
           "Theory":"",
           "SkillsPracticals":"",

            "PerformanceCriteria":[{
            "CriteriaDesc":"",
            "OutOf":"",
            "Theory":"",
            "Skills":""
            }]
    }]

  }]


}
```

and this was my approach in mongo shell(version 3.6)

```
db.test4.update({},
{"$set" : 
{"QP.$[i].CompulsoryNos.$[j].PerformanceCriteria.$[k].Skills" : 
"Talented"}},
{"arrayFilters" : [{"i.qpCode" : "ID_1"},{"j.NosCode" : "Code_1"}, 
{"k.Skills" : "skills_1"}]})
```

is there is any way to implement the same query using mgo?

Comment: What have you actually tried? If you have made an attempt and can't work a part out then that's fine. But right now the question is looking like "write my code for me", so please make it better. Mind you, I would err towards "No" considering the project has not been updated for some time. Usually this requires updates in the driver implementation to accept the `arrayFilters` in the options block.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, as i said, i have tried to update the collection using mongo shell and succeeded, but mgo's update function will accept only two parameters. is there is any workaround or any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can as the signature for the `Update` in mgo does not appear to allow passing such an option. There is an officially supported [MongoDB Go Driver now](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver). There are examples of `arrayFilters` with positional filtered updates in the unit tests. But it would mean converting your project from using mgo to using the alternate driver. The other "possibility" could be to issue the raw database command for the update. But I would really not recommend that, and you're probably better off switching drivers.

Comment: Another option is to wait when it is implemented in the legacy driver https://github.com/globalsign/mgo/issues/179

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/laoluan/mgo
I modified the mgo version

```
_ = session.DB("youdbname").C("test4").UpdateUseAf(
    bson.M{},
    bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"QP.$[i].CompulsoryNos.$[j].PerformanceCriteria.$[k].Skills": "Talented"}},
    []bson.M{
        {"i.qpCode" : "ID_1"},
        {"j.NosCode" : "Code_1"},
        {"k.Skills" : "skills_1"},
    },
)
```